# Discord.js v14 button for browsing embed message pages aren't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js, embed

I'm trying to figure out how to make buttons work in embed message to browse the page with the addresses from the file. I'm able to post the embed message with the addresses and landing on first page, but afterwards I'm not able to browse the pages as the buttons aren't really working at all, first of all I just tried something simple (to move at least by one page forward as I have 300 pages there now), but even that I'm not able to make work.

Code:

```
        let page = 1; // start on the first page

        const totalPages = chunks.length;

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('backwards')
                    .setEmoji('◀️')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('forward')
                    .setEmoji('▶️')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        );
        
        const embedMessage = async (page) => {
          const walletsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#8AC7DB')
            .setAuthor({
              name: bot.username,
              iconURL: bot.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setTitle(` Wallet LIST - Page ${page}/${totalPages}`)
            .setDescription(`${chunks[page - 1].join('\n')}`);
            const reply = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [walletsEmbed], components: [row], ephemeral: true  });
            return reply;
        }
    
        const filter = i => (i.customId === 'forward' || i.customId === 'backwards') && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

        let message = await embedMessage(page);

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            if (i.customId === 'forward') {
                console.log('Button was clicked!')
                await i.deferUpdate();
                page = (page % totalPages) + 1; // wrap around if exceeding last page
                await message.editReply({ embeds: [await embedMessage(page)], components: [row] });
            }
        }); 
      },
    };
```

Error that usual happens(sometimes buttons just do nothing when I tried something)

**Error**

```
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new DiscordjsError(ErrorCodes.InteractionAlreadyReplied);

                                             ^

Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
```

Also the question is, is it even possible to make it work like that in the slashcommand interaction? From what I saw, there is no way for me to edit the embed message with the button pressed.

Comment: Your `embedMessage()` function calls `interaction.reply()` each time it executes. Therefore, if you call embedMessages a second time you would be replying to the same interaction again. Try replying once *outside* the function, then use `interaction.editReply()` inside

Comment: @Elitezen Hi, I have tried but if I try to reply outside of the embed function, it does not know what is that because it's not defined. I will try to play around with it as I think it makes sense what you said, but no idea how to make it to reply only once in the whole call, this likely also would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for the problem. As Elitezen mentioned in the comments, the embed message function called reply everytime and that was causing the problems.

Fixed code with backward button below.

**Code:**

```
        let page = 1; // start on the first page
        const totalPages = chunks.length;

        const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('backwards')
                    .setEmoji('◀️')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('forward')
                    .setEmoji('▶️')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
        );
        
        const embedMessage = async (page) => {
          const walletsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#8AC7DB')
            .setAuthor({
              name: bot.username,
              iconURL: bot.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setTitle(` Wallet LIST - Page ${page}/${totalPages}`)
            .setDescription(`${chunks[page - 1].join('\n')}`);
            return walletsEmbed;
        }
        row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
        if (page === totalPages) {
            row.components[1].setDisabled(true);
        }
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [await embedMessage(page)], components: [row], ephemeral: true  });

        const filter = i => (i.customId === 'forward' || i.customId === 'backwards') && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            try {
            if (i.customId === 'forward') {
                // page = (page % totalPages) + 1; // wrap around if exceeding last page
                page++; // should move 1 page
                console.log('Next pressed! Moving to page:', page)
                if (page === 1) {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(false);
                } else if (page === totalPages) {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(true);
                } else {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(false);
                }
                await i.deferUpdate();
                await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [await embedMessage(page)], components: [row] });
         }  if (i.customId === 'backwards') {
                page--;
                console.log('Back prassed! Moving to page:', page)
                if (page === 1) {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(true);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(false);
                } else if (page === totalPages) {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(true);
                } else {
                    row.components[0].setDisabled(false);
                    row.components[1].setDisabled(false);
                }
                await i.deferUpdate();
                await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [await embedMessage(page)], components: [row] });
            }
            } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }); 
      },
    };
```

Hope this will be helpful for anyone!

Comment: Having the function only return the new embed was a much better idea, well done!

Comment: @Elitezen Thank you! Your comment helped me a lot what to do as I was really stuck with this.